# How can I join multiple tables with TypeORM leftJoinAndSelect?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm

I have:

```
this.createQueryBuilder('company')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('company.companyAdmins', 'companyAdmins')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('companyAdmins.user', 'user')
      .where('company.id = :id', { id })
      .getOne();
```

I want to also get all `invitations` that match that `company`. My `invitation` model has:

```
@Index()
  @ManyToOne(() => Company)
  public company: Company;
```

Comment: Do you have a `@OneToMany` for the relation for the invitations in the `Company` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
this.createQueryBuilder('company')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('company.companyAdmins', 'companyAdmins')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('companyAdmins.user', 'user')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('company.invites', 'invites') // Adding this
  .where('company.id = :id', { id })
  .getOne();
```

Your Company entity should have:

```
@OneToMany(
  type => Invite,
  invite => invite.company,
)
invites?: Invite[];
```